# OpenCV 3.4.0 and CUDA 9.1 Error

Tags: opencv, visual-c++

I am using :
1) Visual Studio 3.4.0 (c++)
2) OpenCV 3.4.0
3) Cuda toolkit 9.1

When I use "labelComponents" in my project then occur a problem :

Now I have another problem :

"OpenCV Error: The function/feature is not implemented (The called functionality is disabled for current build or platform) in throw_no_cuda, file C:\OpenCV 3.4.0\opencv-3.4.0\modules\core\include\opencv2/core/private.cuda.hpp, line 111"

How I can solve this problem ?

Comment: The error says everything.... it is not implemented... you can use the CPU version or implement one yourself (and maybe contribute to OpenCV)

Comment: why ? labelComponents was for old version and then why doesn't exist in new version ?! I need GPU version

Comment: Hmmm it seems that it was moved to the cuda legacy module..... probably it is no longer supported or they had a problem with it :/ couldn't find one in the issues section of their github, so no idea. Maybe you can ask in http://answers.opencv.org/questions/ to get a better answer